# Transparent gradient issue

Tags: android, transparent, linear-gradients

I have layout with google map fragment in FrameLayout. Also, i placed the new view over the map with gradient background.
Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fadeTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fade_height"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/list_fade_top"/>
    <include layout="@layout/top_line_mid_gray"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

list_fade_top:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
              android:startColor="@color/fade_start_color"
              android:centerColor="@color/fade_center_color"
              android:endColor="@color/fade_end_color"
        android:type="linear"/>
</shape>
```

1. start/end and center colors. This gradient draws with 2 light lines:

`<color name="fade_start_color">#00000000</color>
<color name="fade_center_color">#4f000000</color>
<color name="fade_end_color">#ff000000</color>`

[image]

2. start/end and center colors. This gradient draws with a 1 light line:

`<color name="fade_start_color">#00000000</color>
 <color name="fade_center_color">#6f000000</color>
 <color name="fade_end_color">#ff000000</color>`
[image]

3. The same behavior for gradient without center color:

   ```
   <gradient
       android:angle="90"
             android:startColor="@color/fade_start_color"
             android:endColor="@color/fade_end_color"
       android:type="linear"/>
   ```

[image]

How can i draw a smooth linear gradient from black (or semi transparent black) to a full transparent?

I tried hardware acceleration on/off, 'getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);' Nothing helps me.

**Update 1**
I created a simple app at github.
https://github.com/ralexey/TestApp
Just an activity with color background and gradient over it.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your gradient `android:centerY="y%p"`
it may help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerY="25%p"
        android:centerColor="@color/fade_center_color"
        android:endColor="@color/fade_end_color"
        android:startColor="@color/fade_start_color"
        android:type="linear"
        android:dither="true"
        android:useLevel="true" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help too

Comment: add this line `android:dither="true"`

Comment: The result is the same
https://github.com/ralexey/TestApp/blob/prakash_u/app/src/main/res/drawable/list_fade_top.xml

Comment: `android:centerY="50%p"` this with your requirement

Comment: I set 50% just to show the two light lines over the gradient. I can remove the center color and 50% at all, but it will draw the white line at the bottom of the gradient, but i want to get a smooth gradient without this line

Answer (score 0):

try this below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:centerColor="#6f000000"
                android:endColor="#ff000000"
                android:angle="90" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't help me.